# How to give index of array in attribute while creating object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am creating an object in javascript a which is based on some array data

```
var myArr = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "Music": "POP",
        "Singer": "Abc",
        "Country": "IND"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "Music": "JAZZ",
        "Singer": "xyz",
        "Country": "USA"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "Music": "BLUES",
        "Singer": "def",
        "Country": "ENG"
    }
]
```

Now Based on this array I am trying to create an object of array which having

**id, Value and Country.**

Here What I am trying

```
var myObj = [];

for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
    var obj = {
        id: i,
        Value: myArr[i].Music,
        myArr[i].Singer : myArr[i].Country,
    }
    myObj.push(obj);
}
```

But during this for loop `myArr[i].Singer` is throwing an error. How to resolve this.

Comment: So it's Java, not Javascript? Your myArr object doesn't look like Javascript.

Comment: This is a mess- `myArr` is an object, not an array, and it's not even a valid object, the syntax is wrong. `myObj` is actually an array. I don't know how to respond really- can you show what `myArr` actually is in your code? Because as it is right now, this would just throw snytax errors.

Comment: @Walk I updated my question. Thank u for pointing it out

Comment: can you give the output you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With an array, take the wanted key and assign the value directly outside of the object literal.

```js
var myArr = [{ id: 1, Music: "POP", Singer: "Abc", Country: "IND" }, { id: 2, Music: "JAZZ", Singer: "xyz", Country: "USA" }, { id: 3, Music: "BLUES", Singer: "def", Country: "ENG" }],
    myObj = [],
    obj;

for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
    obj = {
        id: i,
        Value: myArr[i].Music
    }
    obj[myArr[i].Singer] = myArr[i].Country;
    myObj.push(obj);
}

console.log(myObj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With ES6 you could use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) and map the object for a new array.

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, Music: "POP", Singer: "Abc", Country: "IND" }, { id: 2, Music: "JAZZ", Singer: "xyz", Country: "USA" }, { id: 3, Music: "BLUES", Singer: "def", Country: "ENG" }],
    result = array.map((o, i) => ({ id: i, Value: o.Music, [o.Singer]: o.Country}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myObj = [];
for(var item in myArr){
    if(item.hasOwnProperty(“Music”){
        myObj .push(item.Music);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#map`.

```js
var myArr = [{"id":1,"Music":"POP","Singer":"Abc","Country": "IND"},{"id":2,"Music":"JAZZ","Singer":"xyz","Country": "USA"},{"id":3,"Music":"BLUES","Singer":"def","Country": "ENG"}];
var result = myArr.map(({Music, Singer, Country}, i) => ({id : i, Value: Music, [Singer] : Country}));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little bit of `ES6/ES7`. Create a new array of objects with the desired props from the existing array of objects.

```
const modifiedArray = myArr.map( item => {
    //This will return only the elements from the object you want
    const picked = (({
        width,
        height,
        type,
        size,
        name
    }) => ({
        width,
        height,
        type,
        size,
        name
    }))(item);
    // Return the object and insert it in the array
    return {
        ...picked,
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
var myArr = [{"id": 1,"Music": "POP","Singer": "Abc","Country": "IND"}, {"id": 2,"Music": "JAZZ","Singer": "xyz","Country": "USA"}, {"id": 3,"Music": "BLUES","Singer": "def","Country": "ENG"}],
    myObj = myArr.map(function (elem, index) {
      return {
        id: index,
        Value: elem.Music,
        [elem.Singer]: elem.Country
      };
    });

console.log(myObj);
```